# Sagemaker endpoint servving doesnt work for multiple inputs (mulit input-output LSTM)

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, amazon-sagemaker, tensorflow-serving

I have a LSTM network that has 3 inputs and 3 outputs(built with [functional api](https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/) in Tf.keras) , that I am trying to deploy as sagemaker endpoint. I have input shape of (None,10,1) for each input/feature, which means 10 timesteps.(I later concatenate the embeddings, but its irrelevant here)

Everything works fine on training time on sagemaker training jobs as well and training completes and artifacts are made successfully. But at time of invocation, endpoint is not working to predict `1 example, having 10 timesteps with 3 inputs` , I have tried multiple things but cant provide three inputs for prediction(input_1,input_2,input_1).

As I said that each input has 10 timesteps, so have shape (10,1). Endpoint only returns the output if I format my payload as below, but by doing so, it treats each time-step as separate example/instance and return 10 predictions for each output

```
{'inputs':{
           'input_1': [[0], [0], [0], [0], [2], [12], [11], [7], [7], [2]],
           'input_2': [[0], [0], [0], [0], [30], [21], [2], [15], [27], [30]],
           'input_3': [[0], [0], [0], [0], [6], [2], [3], [13], [15], [6]]}
          } # gives len(pred['output_1"])) == 10
```

This is expected as it consider this request as 10 examples, but in my case it is one example with 10-timesteps for each feature (1,10,1). So I tried different things from the [documentation](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/tensorflow/deploying_tensorflow_serving.html). Like using instances.

```
{'instances': [
                {
                      'input_1': [[0],[0], [0],[0],[2],[12],[11], [7], [7], [2]],
                      'input_2': [[0], [0], [0], [0], [30], [21], [2], [15], [27], [30]],
                      'input_3': [[0], [0], [0], [0], [6], [2], [3], [13], [15], [6]]
                }
              ]
}
```

But it gives this error.

> transpose expects a vector of size 4. But input(1) is a vector of
> size 3\n\t [[{{node transpose_1}}]]\n\t
> [[functional_1/lstm/PartitionedCall]]\n\t
> [[StatefulPartitionedCall/StatefulPartitionedCall]]"\n}"}"

Document also gives example and says

> for models with multiple named inputs, just include all the keys in the input dict

but when I use this, I get error saying `Missing 'inputs' or 'instances' key\"\n}"`

```
{'input_1': [[0], [0], [0], [0], [2], [12], [11], [7], [7], [2]],
 'input_2': [[0], [0], [0], [0], [30], [21], [2], [15], [27], [30]],
 'input_3': [[0], [0], [0], [0], [6], [2], [3], [13], [15], [6]]}
```

My invocation code is below.

```
import boto3
import json

sm = boto3.client('sagemaker-runtime')    
endpoint_name = "tensorflow--------------------4"
response = sm.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=endpoint_name, 
                              Body=json.dumps(payload),
                              ContentType='application/json')
```

I am not sure how to solve this issue, looking forward for help